# How to rewrite a repo on Git

Tags: git, magento, bitbucket

I'm working on a Magento project, and and I have the directory called `Magento2` init as a git repo. However, I usually work on a repo of `Magento2/app/code/Vendor/Module` and when I have to save my work, I use

`git add app/code/Vendor/Module`

Then commit. As you can guess, the remote repo's source says `app/code/Vendor/Module`. A new project is coming in, and I want to make `Module` as the new git repo for the existing project. Is this a way to disconnect the remote repo with the old one, connect it with the new one and rewrite the structure as desired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this a way to disconnect the remote repository with the old one, connect it with the new one and rewrite the structure as desired?

yes,

Add or update the remote of your git repository.

#### Adding new remote location

```
git remote add <new_name> <new_url>
```

#### Updating current remote location

```
git remote set-url <current name [origin?]> <new_url>
```

#### Verify new/current remote:

```
git remote -v
```